# Example of Dirac Operator that is not Fredholm

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $E$ be a Clifford bundle over $M$ and $D$ be the associated Dirac operator on $E$.

If $M$ is compact then $D$ is a Fredholm operator, since it is elliptic.

I'm wondering whether there are any easy examples of non-compact manifolds $M$ and bundles $E$ where one can show that $D$ is not Fredholm? I would assume $M=\mathbb{R}$ might be one such manifold, but I wasn't sure how to go about proving that the Dirac operator in this case is not Fredholm.

Thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543932/range-of-the-dirac-operator-on-the-real-line-closed/544207